# add property to document in doctrine

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm totally newbie with MongoDb in Symfony using Doctrine and I'm currently in the following situation:

```
MyDocument{
    property1:key1,
    property2:[{{MyDocument2},additionalProperty:key},...]
    ....
}
```

In doctrine I have something like this:

```
class MyDocument{
     /**
     *@MongoDB\String
     */
     $property1;

     /**
     *@MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="MyDocument2")
     */
     $property2 = array();
}
```

Basically my problem is how to append the **additionalProperty** to "MyDocument2" in Doctrine. I suppose that I will have to create an auxiliar document with the aggregation of "MyDocument2" and the "additionalProperty", are there any simpler way to implement this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem I started playing with the inheritance. I created a parent class and then I created a child class which extended from the parent class. I tried to cast to the child class when I needed but it didn't work... :( After my test with the inheritance I managed to solve the problem in the following way:

1) I created the base object class "MyDocument2".

2) I created an auxiliary class with the following structure:

```
class AuxiliaryDocument{

 /**
 *@MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="MyDocument2")
 */
 $myDocument;

 /**
 *@MongoDB\String
 */
 $additionalProperty;
 }
```

3) After the Auxiliary object implementation I only had to change the type inside MyDocument class to:

```
/**
 *@MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="AuxiliaryDocument")
 */
 $property2 = array();
```

I suppose that this isn't the most elegant way to solve the problem, but I think that it's a quick way to solve it.